# Allow Maven to automatically create directories in Ubuntu

Tags: maven, ubuntu

I am running Maven 3.0.4 in Ubuntu 12.04. I have Java version 1.7.0_25. I am trying to use the `mvn package` command, but am continually running into errors, which are always along the lines of:

```
Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error:
javac: directory not found: /......../target/[some folder]
```

I couldn't figure out what this was originally but now understand from some basic googling that this is because the destination directory has to exist. The generally suggested way to handle this problem is to create an ant script which does it for you (I think).

However, I have no idea what folders actually need to be created. This is not my project I'm compiling, just something I've downloaded. Can an Ant script still be used and, if so, could anybody point me in the right direction as I have never used an ant script before, much less created one, and could quite accurately be called a Ubuntu "noob"!

**Full Maven output as requested**

Directory is:

```
flume-sources - containing
    flume.conf
    pom.xml
    src
      main
        java
          com
            cloudera
              flume
                source
                  TwitterSource.java
                  TwitterSourceConstants.java
```

Maven error is:

```
andrew@andrew-VirtualBox:~/flume-sources$ mvn package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building flume-sources 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.3:resources (default-resources) @ flume-sources ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/andrew/flume-sources/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ flume-sources ---
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to /home/andrew/flume-sources/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error:
javac: directory not found: /home/andrew/flume-sources/target/classes
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options

[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.470s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Jul 08 12:35:58 BST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/59M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project flume-sources: Compilation failure
[ERROR] Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error:
[ERROR] javac: directory not found: /home/andrew/flume-sources/target/classes
[ERROR] Usage: javac <options> <source files>
[ERROR] use -help for a list of possible options
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
andrew@andrew-VirtualBox:~/flume-sources$
```

Comment: More output from Maven would be useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you don't need to create the folder by hand or with an ant script.

If the `target` folder doesn't exist when you run mvn, it will create it

So my guess is that you have a permissions issue

The user running maven can't create folders in /home/andrew/flume-sources

just as a test, run mvn as root

```
 sudo mvn package
```

if that works then it is what I said and you will need to 1) `chown` the folder so that the user running maven can create folders in it (rw) or 2) run mvn from the same user that owns the folder (which i'm guessing is `andrew`)

Comment: Flip's sake. After nearly a week of trying, simply using sudo worked. It never occurred to me a user wouldn't have permission, as "andrew" is the chief user of the system. How can I identify who owns a folder (as there only is one user on the machine and it should be andrew?)

Comment: Just figured that one out. ls -l /directory/. It was owned by root. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: i recommend you don't actually run maven as root now that you know what's the problem. The solution is to change the owner of the folder to andrew: `sudo chown -R andrew /home/andrew/flume-sources`

Comment: Exactly what I did. Thanks!